# man not searching ~/.local/share/man/ for man pages

Tags: ubuntu, man

On a previous install of Ubuntu 20.04, `man` would also search in the `XDG_` home folder location in addition to the normal paths, e.g. `/home/naftuli/.local/share/man/man?/*`. For instance, I often installed Rust man pages via:

```bash
rsync -av ~/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/share/man/man1/ \
    ~/.local/share/man/man1/
```

I'm now on Ubuntu 22.04 (elementary OS 7.0), I've done the same thing, yet `man` can't seem to find them:

```bash
$ man cargo
No manual entry for cargo
```

I have uploaded my `/etc/manpath.config` for both 20.04 and 22.04 [to this Gist](https://gist.github.com/naftulikay/7c3dea379bb8112ea49854eca8691b62), and the diff does not seem significant:

```
diff --git a/manpath.config-20.04 b/etc/manpath.config
index a3e2255..e1747a2 100644
--- a/manpath.config-20.04
+++ b/etc/manpath.config
@@ -109,7 +109,7 @@ MANDB_MAP   /snap/man               /var/cache/man/snap
 # particular order. Sections with extensions should usually be adjacent to
 # their main section (e.g. "1 1mh 8 ...").
 #
-SECTION                1 n l 8 3 2 3posix 3pm 3perl 3am 5 4 9 6 7
+SECTION                1 n l 8 3 0 2 3posix 3pm 3perl 3am 5 4 9 6 7
 #
 #---------------------------------------------------------
 # Range of terminal widths permitted when displaying cat pages. If the
@@ -129,4 +129,4 @@ SECTION             1 n l 8 3 2 3posix 3pm 3perl 3am 5 4 9 6 7
 #---------------------------------------------------------
 # Flags.
 # NOCACHE keeps man from creating cat pages.
-#NOCACHE
\ No newline at end of file
+#NOCACHE
```

Is there other configuration I might be missing? I did not have to do anything special on 20.04 to have it find `man` pages in `~/.local/share/man`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what my configuration was on my previous install, as I do not have the hardware with me at the moment, but I was able to discover a way to fix the path.

### Using the `MANPATH` Environment Variable

As per [`manpath(1)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/manpath.1.html), the `MANPATH` environment variable allows a "temporary" (i.e. as long as the environment variable is set) path modification for `man`. The variable content follows the pattern of `PATH`, being colon-delimited, but also allows *prepending*, *appending*, and *inserting* the system `man` path within the hierarchy.

- To *prepend* an entry into the `man` path, have your `MANPATH` variable *end* with a colon: `export MANPATH="$HOME/.local/share/man:`
- To *append* an entry into the `man` path, have your `MANPATH` variable *start* with a colon: `export MANPATH=":$HOME/.local/share/man`
- To *insert* the system `man` path at an arbitrary point, use two colons: `export MANPATH="/snap/man::$HOME/.local/share/man`.

I'd personally prefer to have `man` look in my home directory first before looking for system man pages, so I am setting it like so in my `~/.bashrc` file:

```bash
# note the colon at the end
export MANPATH="$HOME/.local/share/man:"
```

### Using `PATH` to Show the Way

[According to this blog post](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/man-pages-manual-install#the-relationship-between-path-and-search-paths), `MANPATH_MAP` entries in `/etc/manpath.config` tell `man` *how* to find directories containing manual files relevant to a particular entry within `PATH`. `man` then uses these *path relationships* to find `man` files, and this is likely what the difference was for me in my previous install.

For example, consider the following entry:

```
MANPATH_MAP /usr/local/bin /usr/local/share/man
```

What this results in is that when looking for a manual page, `man` will examine the relative path between the executable found in `PATH` and the given entry.

In my new install, I hadn't yet created `~/.local/bin`, which is where I typically keep shell scripts and other local executables in my home directory. After creating this directory, and after spawning a new shell, I was able to run `man cargo` and have it find the manual pages in `~/.local/share/man`.

It's a bit unintuitive, I probably never would have figured this out without diving very deeply into `man`, but it does work!